# i got You tube channel subscription list from first user and last user only.How to retrieve all the subscription list?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I've tried looking in the subscription list i got response from first subscriber username and last subscriber username.i want Retrieve all subscription list here sample code is

```
   SubscriptionSnippet subscriptionsni = new SubscriptionSnippet();
   subscriptionsni.getChannelId();
   YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscriptionList = outube.subscriptions().list("subscriberSnippet,contentDetails").setMySubscribers(true);
   SubscriptionListResponse returnedSubscription1 =subscriptionList.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response should include all.

Try https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=subscriberSnippet%252CcontentDetails&mySubscribers=true&_h=1&